# Why JSDOM enters in an infinite loop when used with Sinon fake timers?

Tags: node.js, sinon, jsdom

With the latest JSDOM (11.6.0), I get an infinite loop when used with Sinon's fake timers.

```
const sinon = require('sinon');

sinon.useFakeTimers();
require('jsdom'); // This line creates an infinite loop
```

How can I avoid this infinite loop?

Answer (score 7):

This is caused by the new Performance API.

The implementation uses Date.now() to calibrate the clock. This is the function:

```
// This function assumes the clock is accurate.
function calculateClockOffset() {
  const start = Date.now();
  let cur = start;
  while (cur === start) {
    cur = Date.now();
  }
  ...
}
```

([source](https://github.com/jsdom/w3c-hr-time/blob/master/lib/calculate-clock-offset.js#L14), note this code is not in JSDOM but in one of its dependencies, w3c-hr-time)

When you run `sinon.useFakeTimers();`, it will mock `Date.now()` to always return the same value, therefore the above code creates an infinite loop.

The workaround is to not mock `Date`, only setTimeout/setInterval functions:

```
// Sinon 2.x
sinon.useFakeTimers('setTimeout', 'clearTimeout', 'setInterval', 'clearInterval');

// Sinon 3.x or higher
sinon.useFakeTimers({toFake:['setTimeout', 'clearTimeout', 'setInterval', 'clearInterval']});
```

Comment: I've used JSDOM and Sinon for years but never managed to hit this specific issue. Nice find!

Comment: w3c-hr-time has been changed to bail out after 1e6 iterations, so this should no longer generate an infinite loop (but still a significant and annoying delay, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

I found another simple workaround, which may be useful if you have to mock `Date`: mock `Date` after creating the `JSDOM` object.